# PHP - retrieve token from header

Tags: php

What is the best way to retrieve token "r9QQ5koqJT_e8iKAqSM2hhj" from header.

```
Host: localhost
Authorization: Bearer r9QQ5koqJT_e8iKAqSM2hhj
Content-Type: application/json
X-Version: 1
Accept: application/json
Content-Length: 61
```

Comment: how are you getting the above initially? There is the `headers_list()` function, if you are using cURL there are other options available.

Answer (score 7):

To read headers, in case you don't already know how to get them, check http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

To get the token, here is sample code

```
<?php
if (substr($header, 0, 7) !== 'Bearer ') {
    return false;
}

return trim(substr($header, 7));
```

Comment: `getallheaders` is for request headers, surely the OP needs response headers

Comment: I think retrieving means request headers, if the OP meant to manipulate response headers it would be "set" not "retrieve".